# Trying to insert current date and time into table with VBA via INSERT INTO SQL command. Receiving run-time error 3134

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

Repeatedly generates Run-Time error '3134': Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement

Here is my code:

```
SqlCode = "INSERT INTO LogT (reps, exerciseID, WorkoutDate, Time) VALUES (30, 1, Date(), Now());"

DoCmd.RunSQL (SqlCode)
```

Comment: The problem appears to be with the format of your <code>EventDate</code> field.
If you use the <code>INSERT</code> statement with the <code>VALUES</code> clause, you have to explicitly specify the correct datatype.
So, if your field is a date/datetime field, use the correct datetime format,
<code>DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [tbl_Event] ([EventName], [EventDate], [EventDescription], [EventType]) VALUES ('" &amp; Me.cboEventName &amp; "', #" &amp; Me.txtEventDate &amp; "#, '" &amp; Me.txtEventDescription &amp; "', '" &amp; Me.cboEventType &amp; "')"
</code>

Comment: I'm sorry Amirreza, but I think you need to reformat your reply or wrap your code in the appropriate markers.  There's a bunch of garbled text and symbols making the syntax impossible to understand.

Comment: @amirreza, no delimiters are need for the SQL as presented. SQL can resolve the Date() and Now() functions - I assume reps and exerciseID are number type.

Comment: @Picayuni, why are you using two fields for workout date and time? Just use one field that saves Now(). I can't see anything wrong with that SQL. Will it execute if used in a query object? Why use SQL instead of data entry with a bound form anyway?

Comment: I found the issue.  I used a reserved word "Time" as a field name.  Changed that, and it worked immediately.  I don't understand why Access didn't warn me about the use of an illegal field name.  And I'm using two fields because it's easier to run queries and manipulate the data without worrying about splitting the date from the time.

Comment: I started to wonder if Time was a reserved word but you figured it out before I could suggest. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html. Two functions that easily separate date and time parts are DateValue() and TimeValue().

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap in brackets:

```
SqlCode = "INSERT INTO LogT (reps, exerciseID, WorkoutDate, [Time]) VALUES (30, 1, Date(), Now());"
```